# Navigation Drawer Template Android Studio 2.1

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-studio, navigation-drawer

I am using the **navigation drawer template** of android studio 2.1 and i'm confuse on how to go to another activity or change the content if one of the item in navigation drawer is click. 
In **OnNavigationItemSelected**! Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically Navigation Drawer from Android Studio provide implementation of **Fragment** any number you add as menu or sub menu where we use FragmentActivity for communication there is different way of implement with activity

[Navigation drawer with activity](https://github.com/j-mateo/MultiActivityToolbar)

Comment: Didn't work.. it closses after i click one of the item in navigation drawer

Comment: @RoyalCediee Check whether you had properly implemented framgent transaction if you had used fragment,and Intent if you had used activity

Comment: I already solve the problem. I didn't implement the transaction of fragments so it closes everytime i click one of the items on the drawer. Thank you.